# Is there an equivalent to `refFromUrl` in google-cloud-storage for Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

The Firebase API provides a convenience function [Storage::refFromUrl](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Storage#refFromURL) ([source](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/database/src/api/Database.ts#L87)) that converts a `URL` into a storage reference.

From [the source (location.ts)](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/storage/src/implementation/location.ts#L64) It looks like it's a straightforward Regular expression.

Is there an equivalent Python method that works with the [`google-cloud-storage`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/client.html#) API to get the bucket and path?

Comment: There's none if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a straightforward regex.  Here's what I put together in a few minutes, based on the reference Javascript implementation:

```
def _urlToBucketPath (url):
    """Convert a Firebase HTTP URL to a (bucket, path) tuple, 
    Firebase's `refFromURL`.
    """
    bucket_domain = '([A-Za-z0-9.\\-]+)'
    is_http = not url.startswith('gs://')

    if is_http:
        path = '(/([^?#]*).*)?$'
        version =  'v[A-Za-z0-9_]+'
        rex = (
            '^https?://firebasestorage\\.googleapis\\.com/' +
            version + '/b/' + bucket_domain + '/o' + path)
    else:
        gs_path = '(/(.*))?$'
        rex = '^gs://' + bucket_domain + gs_path

    matches = re.match(rex, url, re.I)
    if not matches:
        raise Exception('URL does not match a bucket: %s' % url)

    bucket, _, path = matches.groups()

    if is_http:
        path = urllib.parse.unquote(path)

    return (bucket, path)
```

I've asked that it be added to the Firebase features list, and if it shows up I expect it'd be exposed in [firebase_admin.storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.storage)

With the `bucket` and `path` it's straightforward to create a storage reference.